# Javascript game giving wrong output

Tags: javascript

I just completed a few exercises on "CodeAcademy" which taught me to create a rock,paper and scissors game. Everything works fine except the output that I want to receive. I am not getting the out "paper wins". All i get it "paper". I have just started to grasp the foundation of Javascript which is why I am not a strong scripter yet.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random(0);

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {

        return ("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "paper wins";
        } else {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        }
        if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "rock wins";
            } else {
                if (choice2 === "paper") {
                    return "scissors wins";
                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: The code behaves as designed -- you're logging `computerChoice`, not the value returned by `compare()`.

Comment: Your code never calls your `compare()` function anyway. Simply declaring a function just makes it *available* - it doesn't actually *do* anything until it's invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are invoking the compare function on selection of the choices. so you are sending user choice to the function. now you should compare it with computerChoice. what is choice2 there?

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you never call your compare function and you never return any value of that function. And even if you did your function would fail most of the time anyway.

You structure:

```
if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        return "paper wins";
    } else {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") { //is never true because choice1 is always "paper"
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "scissors wins";
            }
        }
    }
} //if choice1 === "paper" ends here
//no love for the rock?
```

What you want to achieve:

```
 if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") 
        {
            return "paper wins";
        } 
        else if (choice2 === "scissors") 
        {
            return "scissors wins";
        }
 } 
 else if (choice1 === "scissors")
 {
       if (choice2 === "rock") 
       {
           return "rock wins";
       } 
       else if (choice2 === "paper") 
       {
           return "scissors wins";
       }
 }
 else if (choice1 === "rock") //don't forget the rock
 {
       if (choice2 === "paper") 
       {
           return "paper wins";
       } 
       else if (choice2 === "scissors") 
       {
           return "rock wins";
       }
 }
```

Then you will have to call your function like this:

```
var result = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

And you log the `result` variable. In your example you logged `computerChoice` which can only be "paper", "scissors" or "rock" because that is the value you give it, not the value of the function.

Since you let the user type in anything he/she wants you will obviously also have to validate their input or the if/else structure will fail.